# Disable bullets in royalslider if only one image

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using the HTML version of royalslider. In the dynamic instantiation of the slider, a single bullet is used when only one slide is present. I'm trying to remove this bullet using the built-in royalslider API method: "slider.numSlides". I'm very, very new to jQuery/javascript so it's a struggle for me. Here's my code.

```
/* remove bullets if less than one image is in the slider */
var slider = $('.royalSlider').data('royalSlider'); 
var updateURL = function() {
if('slider.numSlides' < 2){$( ".rsBullets" ).remove(); 
}else{ 
    $(".rsBullets").fadeIn(300); 
} 
};
```

I would greatly appreciate any insight. Thanks.

Comment: share the link. which slider you are using.

Comment: here's the link: http://c1358.paas2.tx.modxcloud.com/index.php?id=52 and I'm using a customized video slider

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it something like this:

```
var slider = $('.royalSlider'), 
nav = slider.find('.rsBullets');
if (slider.data('royalSlider').numSlides <= 1) { 
nav.hide(); 
}
else {
    nav.show();
    }
```

Hope this helps.
[Source](http://help.dimsemenov.com/discussions/problems/5310-hide-single-bullet)

Comment: Magic. You meant "<=2" btw. Thanks so much -- I've been working on that forever.

Comment: @Fahad i'm trying to do the same thing. Where do I put this code? Within the same script tags as the royalslider jquery? I tried that but it didn't work. I also tried putting it within different script tags. Looks like I'm missing something basic here.